# How to extract a time from a variable and compared it with the current time in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, datetime

I'm using the qhue api for philips hue in python. With it I am able to obtain the last time one of my hue switches was clicked to turn on the lights. And it is given to me in this format:

```
2020-03-24T16:10:54
```

How could I compare that date and time with the current time with `datetime.datetime.now()` so my code is able to tell when the button is pressed or not so that I can trigger another event to happen when the button is clicked?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Have a look at [Converting Strings to datetime in Python](https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/)

Comment: @AlexandreB. I haven't tried anything because I have no clue how to get from A to B, which is why I asked. The datetime thats returned is already a string I believe.

Comment: @AlexandreB. could I change the returned value that is show in my question into a Unix time code stamp and then compare that to the current unix time code stamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a string, you can transform it to python `datetime` using the [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

```
# import datetime module
from datetime import datetime

# Your input string date
date_time_str = '2020-03-24T16:10:54'

# convert string to python datetime object
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
print(date_time_obj)
# 2020-03-24 16:10:54
```

Once you have a python `datetime` object, you can compare with the current datetime:

```
# get current date
now = datetime.today()
print(now)
# 2020-03-24 17:50:06.774388

# do some comparison
if (now < date_time_obj): 
    print("{} < {}".format(now, date_time_obj))
else:
    print("{} < {}".format(date_time_obj, now))
# 2020-03-24 16:10:54 < 2020-03-24 17:50:06.774388
```

Hope that helps !